# Image is not resizable in TabView on IOS 14.5

Tags: ios, swiftui

After updated Xcode to version 12.5, I noticed that Images are not resizable in TabView for only IOS 14.5.

Anyone noticed the issue or anything has changed in the new version?

```
TabView { 
    Image("ic_any_image")
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFit()
        .padding()
    }
    .tag(0)                                
}
.frame(maxHeight: UIScreen.main.bounds.width)
.tabViewStyle(PageTabViewStyle())
```

Comment: It's working here. Do you mean on a specific device? Real or simulated?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini it doesn't work on both simulator or real device for IOS 14.5. Other OS versions are fine.

Comment: I've tested on both device and simulator with iOS 14.5 and it worked. Are  you sure you don't have any other modifier with some sideefects?

Comment: also works for me, IOS 14.5, however I have the .frame(...) and .tabViewStyle(...) just after the .tag(0) modifying the TabView.